# ¿Cómo hago para evitar que VSCode me apile el código al darle ctrl + s?

Tags: flutter, vscode, dart

Simplemente no quiero que VSCode me mueva el código a como lo pongo inicialmente, no sé si es una configuración o es alguna extensión.

Un ejemplo cualquiera de como lo pongo:

[image]

Y luego cómo lo deja al dar ctrl + s.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Ve a tus preferencias (*File* > *Preferences* > *Settings* o  presiona `Ctrl` + `,`) y en la sección *Text Editor* > *Formatting* desmarca la casilla *Format on Save*. Eso evitará que se autoformatee el código cada vez que guardas los cambios.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]